# Why the sum of all the elements in Edge detection kernel is zero?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, sobel

For example, In Sobel operator, the Sobel Kernel,

```
Gx = [-1 0 +1;
      -2 0 +2; 
      -1 0 +1];

Gy = [+1 +2 +1;
       0  0  0; 
      -1 -2 -1];
```

Why the sum is zero? Is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An edge kernel is a highpass filter. Low frequencies shall be supressed, high frequencies shall pass such a filter. Edges are parts of an image with a high change of signal (gray value) and so high frequencies.

If you design such a filter in frequency domain, it will have zeros at low frequencies and bigger values at higher frequencies. When transforming this into spatial domain (to get a kernel like you described), this will always result in a kernel, where the sum is zero.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more in that second point?

Answer (score 4):

If the sum of the weights were not zero, then a region of the image that was completely uniform would be found to have a non-zero gradient. This is contrary to the definition of what a [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) is.

Comment: Interesting answer.

Comment: This one is the logical answer.
"This means that in a low-frequency part of an image, where the gray values are similar, the result of using this filter is that the corresponding gray values in the new image will be close to zero." - Alasdair McAndrew, An Introduction to Digital Image
Processing with Matlab